# Apache2 access.log different for same packets

Tags: php, c++, apache, winapi, wininet

I have a C++ program that is attempting to upload a file using a PHP application running on an Apache2 webserver. I am having a very weird issue that I am not sure what to do about. So I create the HTTP request using httpSendRequest() function and it appears to be properly formatted when viewed in wireshark [image: wireshark image]. However the file is not uploaded and when I view the access.log file for apache it shows no user agent or content length despite both clearly existing in the packet capture. [image: apache error image]

For reference the requests that returned a 200 status are the same packet sent using burp suite instead of my program using httpSendRequest, and I am also successfully able to upload a file using a web browser.

Here is the code for creating the request using httpSendRequest most of which was taken directly from [this codeguru post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?547165-RESOLVED-Problems-to-send-binary-data-(-BMP-file)-to-php-script).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>


#define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
#define ERROR_MEMORY          11
#define ERROR_SIZE            12
#define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
#define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
#define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
#define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // Local variables
   static char *filename   = "test.txt";   //Filename to be loaded
   static char *type       = "image/jpg";
   static char boundary[]  = "PaulRules";            //Header boundary
   static char nameForm[]  = "fileToUpload";     //Input form name
   static char iaddr[]     = "192.168.0.105";        //IP address
   static char url[]       = "upload.php";         //URL

   char hdrs[255];                  //Headers
   char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
   char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
   FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
   long lSize;                      //File size
   size_t result;


   // Open file
   pFile = fopen ( filename , "rb" );
   if (pFile==NULL) return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;

   // obtain file size:
   fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
   lSize = ftell (pFile);
   rewind (pFile);

   // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
   content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
   if (content == NULL) return ERROR_MEMORY;

   // copy the file into the buffer:
   result = fread (content,1,lSize,pFile);
   if (result != lSize) return ERROR_SIZE;

   // terminate
   fclose (pFile);

   //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
   buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

   //print header
   sprintf(hdrs,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s",boundary);
   sprintf(buffer,"--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"test.bmp\"\r\n",boundary,nameForm,filename);
   sprintf(buffer,"%sContent-Type: %s\r\n\r\n",buffer,type);

   int cb = strlen(buffer);
   char * bp = buffer + cb;
   memcpy(bp, content, lSize);
   bp += lSize;
   int cw = sprintf(bp,"\r\n--%s--\r\n",boundary);

   //Open internet connection
   HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("Paul was here :)",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
   if(hSession==NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN;

   HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
   if(hConnect==NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;

   HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",url, NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*", 0, 1);
   if(hRequest==NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_REQ;

   BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, cb + lSize + cw);
   if(!sent) return ERROR_INTERNET_SEND;

   //close any valid internet-handles
   InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
   InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
   InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

   return 0;
}
```

And here is the PHP script on the server side

```
<?php
$target_dir = "recvFile/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "File already exists";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "File to large";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "ERROR File not uploaded";
}

//attempt to upload the file
else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo "Command:1";
    }
    else {
        echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        echo "ERROR uploading file";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is a colon a legal character in the User-Agent's product token?

Comment: @IInspectable I am fairly sure it is legal however I got rid of it anyway because it is unnecessary. Regardless the same issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source file is `"test.txt"` but you are uploading to `"test.bmp"`. Make them have the same extension.

```
type = "image/jpg";
```

Change `type` to `"image/*"` or `"text/*"` if this is supposed to be text.

Your operation is probably successful seeing that it prints `"Command 1"`. The file is probably there, but it's not the one you expect. If not, see what error you can extract from PHP side.

```
sprintf(buffer,"--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; \
name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"test.bmp\"\r\n",
boundary,nameForm,filename);
```

You have one format specifier `"%s"` and 4 parameters. Remove the last two parameters.

Use [`HttpOpenRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233(v=vs.85).aspx) the way it is recommended:

```
const char *accept[] = { "image/*", NULL }; // or `"text/*"`
HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST",url, NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
```

---

Code using C++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

int main()
{
    HINTERNET hsession = NULL;
    HINTERNET hconnect = NULL;
    HINTERNET hrequest = NULL;

    const char* server = "localhost";
    const char* url = "upload.php";
    const char* type = "image/*";
    std::string filename = "test.bmp";

    std::ifstream infile("c:\\test\\test.bmp", std::ios::binary);
    if(!infile) 
        return 0;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << infile.rdbuf();

    std::string headers = "Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=uniquestring";

    std::string data = "--uniquestring\r\n\
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"%1\"\r\n\
Content-Type: %2\r\n\
\r\n\
%3\r\n\
--uniquestring--";

    data.replace(data.find("%1"), 2, filename);
    data.replace(data.find("%2"), 2, type);
    data.replace(data.find("%3"), 2, oss.str());

    hsession = InternetOpen("appname", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(!hsession) 
        goto cleanup;

    hconnect = InternetConnect(hsession, server, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
        NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    if(!hconnect)
        goto cleanup;

    const char *accept[] = { type, NULL };
    hrequest = HttpOpenRequest(hconnect, "POST", url, NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
    if(!hrequest)
        goto cleanup;

    BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hrequest, headers.data(), headers.size(), 
        &data[0], data.size());
    if(sent)
    {
        DWORD bufsize = 4096;
        std::string read(bufsize, 0);
        InternetReadFile(hrequest, &read[0], bufsize, &bufsize);
        read.resize(bufsize);
        std::cout << read << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

cleanup:
    if(hrequest) InternetCloseHandle(hrequest);
    if(hconnect) InternetCloseHandle(hconnect);
    if(hsession) InternetCloseHandle(hsession);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well you were indeed correct the server was breaking when I attempted to upload a .txt file as a .jpg. Thanks for all the help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Okay good. Your code is C by the way, I added C++ 11 code to make things easier here.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness here is the fully operational code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   // Local variables
   static char *filename   = "Desert.jpg";   //Filename to be loaded
   static char *type       = "multipart/form-data";
   static char boundary[]  = "PaulRules";            //Header boundary
   static char nameForm[]  = "fileToUpload";     //Input form name
   static char iaddr[]     = "192.168.0.105";        //IP address
   static char url[]       = "upload.php";         //URL

   char hdrs[255];                  //Headers
   char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
   char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
   FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
   long lSize;                      //File size
   size_t result;


   // Open file
   pFile = fopen ( filename , "rb" );

   // obtain file size:
   fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
   lSize = ftell (pFile);
   rewind (pFile);

   // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
   content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);

   // copy the file into the buffer:
   result = fread (content,1,lSize,pFile);

   // terminate
   fclose (pFile);

   //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
   buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

   //print header
   sprintf(hdrs,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s",boundary);
   sprintf(buffer,"--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n",boundary, filename);
   sprintf(buffer,"%sContent-Type: %s\r\n\r\n",buffer,type);

   int cb = strlen(buffer);
   char * bp = buffer + cb;
   memcpy(bp, content, lSize);
   bp += lSize;
   int cw = sprintf(bp,"\r\n--%s--\r\n",boundary);

   //Open internet connection
   HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("Winsock",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

   HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);

   const char* accept[] = {"*/*", NULL};
   HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",url, NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);

   BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, cb + lSize + cw);

   DWORD dwSize, dwRead;
   CHAR szBuffer[1024];
   if(!InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize, 0, 0)){
      std::cout << "QUERYDATA ERROR: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
   }
   else{
      while(InternetReadFile(hRequest, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)-1, &dwRead) && dwRead) {
        szBuffer[dwRead] = 0;
        dwRead=0;
      }
      cout << szBuffer;
   }

   //close any valid internet-handles
   InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
   InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
   InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

   return 0;
}
```